# How to initiate ojet menu from javascript

Tags: javascript, java, oracle, jet

We are using below function in java script to trigger oj-dialog and its working fine.

```
else if(operation === "fmethod"){
            
            var popup = document.getElementById("fPopUp");
            if (!popup.isOpen()) {
                popup.open();
            }
            return;
```

But when I am using the same function to trigger oj-menu or any other oj element we are getting "popup.isOpen is not a funtion" error.

Can someone let me know what should be the equivalent syntax of javascript to trigger or start oj-menu.

Answer (score 0):

oj-menu component is not a popup component. So initiate oj-menu we have to use it along with oj-menu-button component.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).